# Pascal - read/readln function impurities?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm really interested - why do you need to put

```
readln;
```

line after reading some value from keyboard into variable? For example,

```
repeat
writeln('Make your choise');
read(CH);

if (CH = '1') then begin
writeln('1');
end;

{ ... }
until CH = 'q';
```

If you run the following code, and press '1' on keyboard, you get an output like

```
1
Make your choise
Make your choise
Make your choise
```

On the other hand, if you add that "readln;" line, it all works perfect:

```
repeat
writeln('Make your choise');
read(CH);
readln;

if (CH = '1') then begin
    Writeln('1');
end

until CH = 'q';
```

My only guess is that calling **readln** without arguments terminates the process of reading the keyboard input. But if so, why cant the read/readln functions stop reading input themselves, to avoid such a clumsiness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`read` reads a character, but still expects Enter to be pressed before returning, even though it only returns 1 character.  You're pressing Enter after 1, and the console is stuffing the keyboard buffer with a `CR` (ASCII 0xd) and a `LF` (ASCII 0xa).  (On a Linux/UNIX system, `Make your choise` will only appears twice, because UNIX uses only a `LF` as its linefeed character).  You can see these by printing the values of the character received with `ord(CH)` (iirc).

The second program is pulling the CRLF combo out of the keyboard buffer with the subsequent `readln` and discarding it, so it behaves in the way you seem to want.

If this is a throwaway program, just do it via `readln`, and go on to solve whatever more important problem you're working on.  If it's destined for production, build up an input function via a loop of some sort around `readkey` (which returns immediately after one character).

Thanks for the nostalgia.